# Balloon tooltip not display in systemtray

Tags: vb.net, system-tray

I set my NotifyIcon of the boot form as follows:

[![
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjK3b.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjK3b.png)

thinking about getting something like:

[image]

But it doesn't show me anything when I hover over the icona in the systemtray. How come? what am I wrong

Comment: Have you set the Text property of the `NotifyIcon` (component?) to something? Have you subscribed to, for example, the MouseClick event, where you show the BalloonTip (e.g., `myNotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip([TimeOut])` or `myNotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip([TimeOut], [Title], [Text], [Icon])`)? What's set in the Text property will show when you hover the icon in the Notification Area.

Comment: I set the text property to: GEA4YOU...
and in the form_load I entered: Me.nIcon.ShowBalloonTip(2000)

Comment: ...so, when the Form is loaded, you can see a Balloon that shows what you have set in the `BalloonTipText` and `BalloonTipTile` properties...

Comment: ...and (as already mentioned) when you hover the notification area Icon, you see what you have set in the `NotifyIcon.Text` property. The, of course, you handle the NotifyIcon's `Click`, `MouseClick` etc. events. Note that if you show NotifyIcon in the Load event and an error is generated, the Load event just exits without, well, *notification* (the exception is eaten up and any remaining code is not run).

Comment: the properties of my NotifyIcon (nIcon) are set at the project level.
Only in the boot form_load I put: Me.nIcon.ShowBalloonTip(2000).
But the balloon is not shown now at startup I am sent a message in windows notification (I windows 10)
Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1):

The balloon is only shown when you call NotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(timeout), not when you hover on the system tray icon, and it uses BalloonTipText and BalloonTipTile properties. You have to handle this method in some event or function.
For example, you could do this when you minimize the form:

```
NotifyIcon.Visible = True
NotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(2000, "MyApp", "The program is still running!", ToolTipIcon.Info)
```

When you hover on the icon and the icon is visible, instead, only a tooltip appears. The tooltip displays the string set in the Text property and doesn't use BalloonTipText and BalloonTipTile.
So you don't have to handle the hover, the ToolTip should automatically appear.
If the issue persists, try to set Visible = False in the designer in order to see whether setting Visible = True works and make sure that there isn't any instruction that throws exception before the ShowBalloonTip method.